# How do I get a GPS location update synchronously in Android using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, gps, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Specifically I am doing C# development using Xamarin.Forms, however working on the native Android side writing a GPS wrapper class which will be usable in the Xamarin.Forms side via dependency injection. The calls should be the same between C# and Java in regards to Android for the most part.

Essentially, I have this method in my Geolocator object (which implements ILocationListener) on the Android side:

```
public async Task<Tuple<bool, string, GPSData>> GetGPSData() {
        gpsData = null;
        var success = false;
        var error = string.Empty;

        if (!manager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider)) {
            //request permission or location services enabling
            //set error
        } else {
            manager.RequestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GpsProvider, this, null);
            success = true;
        }

        return new Tuple<bool, string, GPSData>(success, error, gpsData);
 }
```

and

```
 public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {
        gpsData = new GPSData(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
    }
```

I want to be able to call GetGPSData and have it return the tuple, which for now the only important thing about the Tuple is gpsData is filled in. I know it can take seconds to find a fix, so I want this method to be async and be awaitable in the Xamarin.Forms side once I actually need the value.

My issue is I can't figure out a way to have manager.RequestSingleUpdate work synchronously, or any work around. You call that method, and then eventually OnLocationChanged fires off. I tried throwing in a disgusting, barbaric

```
 while (gpsData == null);
```

after the call to force it not to continue until OnLocationChanged was fired, however when I put that line in, OnLocationChanged never gets called. I'm assuming that is because OnLocationChanged is invoked on the same thread instead of being a background thread.

Is there any way for me to take this scenario and have GetGPSData not return until OnLocationChanged has fired off?

Thanks

EDIT: To add, this method will not be regularly called. It's spontaneous and rare, so I don't want to use RequestLocationUpdates, get regular updates and return the most recent one because that would require always having GPS on, while would rain batteries unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with a `TaskCompletionSource`. I had the same issue and this is how I solved it:

```
TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<bool, string, GPSData> tcs;
// No need for the method to be async, as nothing is await-ed inside it.
public Task<Tuple<bool, string, GPSData>> GetGPSData() {
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<bool, string, GPSData>>();
    gpsData = null;
    var success = false;
    var error = string.Empty;

    if (!manager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider)) {
        //request permission or location services enabling
        //set error
        tcs.TrySetException(new Exception("some error")); // This will throw on the await-ing caller of this method.
    } else {
        manager.RequestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GpsProvider, this, null);
        success = true;
    }

    //return new Tuple<bool, string, GPSData>(success, error, gpsData); <-- change this to:
    return this.tcs.Task;
}
```

And:

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {
        gpsData = new GPSData(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        // Here you set the result of TaskCompletionSource. Your other method completes the task and returns the result to its caller.
        tcs.TrySetResult(new Tuple<bool, string, GPSData>(false, "someString", gpsData));
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much. A note to future people though, calling Wait on the returning task will cause OnLocationChanged to never be invoked (meaning no task result is ever set) since OnLocationChanged needs to be invoked by the same thread that called RequestSIngleUpdate. If you block the thread, everything will hang forever. Use ContinueWith() on the result to assign the work without blocking the thread.

Comment: @Carson or, you could just do: var result = await GetGPSData();